# Read pin (power led) from port expander on ic2-0 at config.txt

Tags: pi-3, gpio, config.txt, bootloader

In `config.txt` you can have conditional booting based on the GPIO pin level, e.g. the `gpio4=1` line.

Is it also possible to access the pin on the GPIO port extender at i2c-0, or is this something loaded with the Linux kernel ?

The reason I am asking is that I would like to read the POWER LED value (under-voltage).

Comment: Not sure, but it's unlikely that's possible. You can get that sort of information in other ways using `vcgencmd` and there are also interfaces to the mailbox interface.